# How to get the object element in an array that has the nearest number?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to find the object element in an array that has the nearest number.

Here's my code:

```
var target = 13;
var arr = [{num: 1}, {num: 10}, {num: 20}];
```

In this example, I expect to get the index `1` as a result which has the nearest number `10`.

If there are multiple nearest elements, I only need one of them.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var target = 13;
var arr = [{num: 1}, {num: 10}, {num: 20}];


const find = (arr, target) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, { num }, index) => {
    return (Math.abs(num - target) < Math.abs(acc.num - target) ? {num, index} : acc)}, {num: 0, index: 0});
}
        
console.log(find(arr, target));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var target = 13;
var arr = [{ num: 1 }, { num: 10 }, { num: 11 }, { num: 13 }, { num: 20 }];

let sol = null;
let solIndex = 0;
let lowestDiff = 999999;

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let diff = Math.abs(13 - arr[i]["num"]);
  if (diff < lowestDiff) {
     lowestDiff = diff;
     sol = null;
     solIndex = i;
     sol = arr[i];
  }
}

console.log("Object: ", sol, "\nIndex: ", solIndex);
```